# Is it possible to trigger the onbeforeunload event programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dom-events

I'm currently using the [jquery-form-observe](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-form-observe/) plugin which uses onbeforeunload to prompt the user about "unsaved" changes.

But I have a scenario where I need to trigger this on a button click: the button click ultimately leads to the page changing, but I want to prompt the user before they start the process that the button click kicks off...

So is there a way to trigger onbeforeunload through jQuery or otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a direct way to do this, but you could always emulate the browser's confirmation box yourself. Here's a simple function I cooked up based on the [specs at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
function triggerBeforeUnload() {
  var event = {};
  handler(event);

  if (typeof event.returnValue == 'undefined' ||
      confirm('Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?\n\n' + event.returnValue + '\n\nPress OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current page.')) {
    // Continue with page unload
  } else {
    // Cancel page unload
  }
}
```

**Edit:** In `jquery.formobserver.js`, right after the definition of `function beforeunload(e) { ... }`, add this line:

```
handler = beforeunload;
```

Note the change in the original code: `window.onbeforeunload` has been replaced by `handler`.

Comment: On both Firefox and IE8 I get an error on the call to window.onbeforeunload.  Firefox error is "window.onbeforeunload is not a function" and IE comes back with "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that the plugin attaches an event handler through `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` and not directly through `window.onbeforeunload`. I guess you'll have to modify the plugin code to get a reference to the `beforeunload` function.

Comment: Thanks! That works now.  Any suggestions on avoiding using a global for handler though?

Comment: Not that I can think of. It shouldn't be a problem though, just rename `handler` to something that won't possibly conflict with another name.

Comment: @casablanca can you make a fiddle for this

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(window).trigger('beforeunload');
});
```

Comment: That was pretty much the first thing I tried, but it seems trigger cannot be used on 'beforeunload' as nothing seems to happen when I call it.

Comment: @mutex I was wondering the same thing before I answered so I set up this simple test: http://jsfiddle.net/LpGq9/.  Perhaps it has to do with how the form observe plugin is binding the onbeforeunload event handler.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. The plugin doesn't use bind; it does this instead:

if(window.attachEvent){
          window.attachEvent('onbeforeunload', beforeunload);
      }else if(window.addEventListener){
          window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeunload, true);
      }