# How to trigger the FineUploader in-progress warning manually?

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

FineUploader triggers a warning if files are in progress and the window is reloaded. I am trying to trigger that warning on AJAX events (we use pjax for navigation). To do so I trigger the "beforeunload" event. The fineUploader in-progress warning does not fire. In the FineUploader code that warning seems to be bound to the beforeunload event (in _preventLeaveInProgress). My question is, why would the FineUploader in-progress warning not fire on the beforeunload event when triggered in code?

Test case: http://beardytaper.com/sandbox/fu/

Example code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fine-uploader').fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: 'server/handleUploads'
          }
    });

    $( window ).bind( "beforeunload", function() {
        console.log('in beforeunload');
    });

    $('#btnUnload').click(function () {
        $( window ).trigger( "beforeunload");
    });

  });
```

Comment: @RayNicholus I do not believe it is a duplicate - the code in my question triggers the onbeforeunload event programmatically and it is fired, again as per the example code. But FineUploader doesn't respond to that event when triggered programmatically and why it does not is my question here. I don't see anything in the referenced question that could help me with that.

Comment: I don't believe you can simply trigger such an event as you might expect.  This is why I marked as a duplicate.  Did you even read [the linked question or the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490331/is-it-possible-to-trigger-the-onbeforeunload-event-programmatically)?  I'm guessing the event handler is not even hit.  You haven't mentioned if the event handler is hit or not.  If Fine Uploader's event handler is not even hit, then this is most definitely not a Fine Uploader issue and this is in fact a duplicate, as I initially suspected.

Comment: @RayNicholus I did read the linked question. I had read it before I posted mine actually but didn't see anything in the question that could help with my issue. The event handler I was using in my code,

Comment: @RayNicholus I did read the linked question. I had read it before I posted mine actually but didn't see anything in the question that could help with my issue. The event handler I was using in my code, the console.log call, is hit. That is attached with the jquery bind method. The FineUploader event handler is not hit, no, and why not is what I am asking for help in figuring out. Might it be related to how FineUploader attaches its event handlers? That is why I tagged it as a FineUploader issue. The code above and the linked test case shows clearly that the beforeunload event is firing.

Comment: Apologies for duplicate and truncated post

Answer (score 0):

If the Fine Uploader event handler isn't even being called, then there is some issue with your code.  That event handler is not meant to be triggered from integration code programmatically anyway.  I suggest you create your own event handler and trigger it for your specific scenario instead.

Also it doesn't make much sense to trigger this event in your code.  It is called when the page starts to reload, so, if you'd like to see it invoked, programmatically reload.