# Javascript: Programmatically trigger onbeforeunload/onunload event

Tags: javascript, events, onbeforeunload

How can I programmatically trigger onbeforeunload and onunload events?(No jquery please). I've tried:

```js
var event = new Event('onbeforeunload');
event.initEvent("onbeforeunload", true, true);
window.document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490331/is-it-possible-to-trigger-the-onbeforeunload-event-programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to trigger the onbeforeunload event programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490331/is-it-possible-to-trigger-the-onbeforeunload-event-programmatically)

Comment: Note: The above mentioned articles refer to jQuery based solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use

```
object.onunload=function(){myScript};
```

or the addEventListener() method:

```
object.addEventListener("unload", myScript);
```

to trigger the event use
object.unload();

Comment: Given the case that we have `window.onbeforeunload=function(){return "you are leaving";}` , if I call `window.onbeforeunload`, no alert box would pop up, but if I call `window.location = 'http://someotherdomain.com'` which will eventually trigger onbeforeunload, I see a pop up with the string "you are leaving". So is there a way to simulate leaving a page completely as it happens when we close a window?!(obviously I'm not looking for window.close())

Comment: I think the question is about programmatically triggering the browser confirmation that onbeforeunload creates. This answer doesn't really accomplish that.

Answer (score 18):

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('beforeunload'))
```

I think this would be the best way in 2020. In case anyone finds this.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload',()=>{console.log("beforeunload triggered")})
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('beforeunload'))
```