# jQuery trigger beforeunload event programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, onbeforeunload

I am trying to invoke browser's onbeforeupload event with jQuery as under:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function (){
    $(window).trigger('beforeunload');
})

</script>
```

It doesn't display browser's default onunload event confirm box which means beforeunload event is not getting fired.

How can I trigger beforeunload event?

Comment: Have you attached a handler breaking the unload process?

Comment: I wanted to display the confirm box with two buttons i.e. Leave Page, Stay on page. I thought it should be triggered since I invoked it

Comment: It's just an event that occurs after certain actions. If you just trigger it, it won't lead to 'leaving' actions. Here is the list of actions which triggers this event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that showing confirmation dialog is the default behavior?

The [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) says:

> When this event returns a non-void value, the user is prompted to
>   confirm the page unload. In most browsers, the return value of the
>   event is displayed in this dialog. In Firefox 4 and later the returned
>   string is not displayed to the user. Instead, Firefox displays the
>   string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave -
>   data you have entered may not be saved." See bug 588292.
>
> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to
>   window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be
>   ignored during this event. See the HTML5 specification for more
>   details.
>
> Note also that various mobile browsers ignore the result of the event
>   (that is, they do not ask the user for confirmation). Firefox has a
>   hidden preference in about:config to do the same. In essence this
>   means the user always confirms that the document may be unloaded.
>
> You can and should handle this event through window.addEventListener()
>   and the beforeunload event. More documentation is available there.

Because of that, you need to add a handler for the event beforehand:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
   ...
});
```

Other ways:

- [Is it possible to trigger the onbeforeunload event programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490331/is-it-possible-to-trigger-the-onbeforeunload-event-programmatically)
- [Javascript: Programmatically trigger onbeforeunload/onunload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495381/javascript-programmatically-trigger-onbeforeunload-onunload-event)

Comment: Thanks, I understood that.